# Navigate to particular activity android

Tags: android

I have a requirement for ICS and above where in there should be multiple instances of an activity.Say i have an activity home then home1,home2,home3 ahould be possible.
There is a series of buttons below which names home1,home2,home3.If i click on home2 that particular instance of home should be popped up keeping the remaining screens in background.ie home 2 should be visible whereas home1 and home3 should still be in background.
I have come across NavUtils but it is killing the remaining activities which should not happen.

Please let me know your valuable suggestions on this.

Comment: did you try playing with activity manager and activity flags to achieve this.

Comment: By using ActivityManager i can get list of tasks but how can i open a particular task?

Comment: If the activities are multiple instances of the same `Activity`, how you'd plan on differentiating between them when attempting to show 'home2' again from the backstack? I can see how it would work with instances of different `Activity` classes, potentially leveraging the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` flag, but not with instances of the same `Activity`.

Comment: @MH,yes i have just gone through the same flag.What i have found is that it returns you the last instance of the Activity.Is there any possibility that i can get that particular instance mapped by getIntent()

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to 
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html
This will give u an idea how to deal with the activities instances.
By default until u press Back key or call finish() explicitly, acitivity will not be finished.

Comment: My issue is how to navigate to a particular activity in the stack without making it singleInstance